# Charpit's method for a system of nonlinear partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a highly nonlinear set of coupled PDEs. I know I will eventually need to solve them numerically, but first I need to understand *how* equations of this type should be solved. Essentially, I have

$$ \nabla \cdot \mathbb{A} = \mathbf{b} $$

$$ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{b} = x $$

where $\mathbb{A}$ is a second-rank tensor, $\mathbf{b}$ is a vector, and $x$ is a scalar. There are three unknown functions, and three equations (due to a symmetry argument, one equation is redundant).

## Solution attempts

- At first, I tried a brute-force approach using finite differences. Even when I simplified the equations as far as I could, this method did not work, so I feel like more mathematical thought is needed here.
- I have followed the notes [here](http://math.iisc.ernet.in/~prasad/prasad/preprints/2013_140528_first_order_PDE_characteristics_only.pdf) (see Section 4) for learning Charpit's method and possibly applying it. However, it does not seem to generalize to more than one unknown function.

## My question

Is there a technique that is typically used to solve a PDE of the type I have described? Charpit's method looked promising, but I can only find examples for a PDE in one unknown function.

Comment: The equations you wrote down are linear. Can you please clarify what is "highly non-linear" about this question?

Comment: Sorry, @user619894, I should have been more clear. Every term (A, b, x) is nonlinear in the unknown functions; I didn't mean that the differential operators were nonlinear.